# I need to filter an array in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter, angularjs-ng-repeat

I need to filter an array that shown below by "all permission value" to send it on the server. It is an example. Thanks for any help.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html ng-app>
    <head>
        <script src="./angular.js"></script>
    <script>

        function MainCtrl($scope) {
            $scope.accounts = [{ name: 'KL', company: 'Alpha', permission: 'all'},
                               { name: 'Jem', company: 'Altes', permission: 'no' },
                               { name: 'Osama', company: 'Solar', permission: 'no' },
                               { name: 'Victor', company: 'Osteriks', permission: 'all' }];

            // I'd like to get here a filtered array by "all permission" from the View block filter

            $scope.filteredAccounts = // [ { name: 'KL', company: 'Alpha', permission: 'all'},
                                    //  { name: 'Victor', company: 'Osteriks', permission: 'all' }];
        }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
        <div ng-repeat="account in accounts | filter: { permission: 'all' }">
            <p>{{ account.name }}</p>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't feel like including underscore or lodash in my project just because i wanted the findWhere function so i added it to angular myself:

simply include this outside of angular and change the "angular.element(document)" to the element you booted your app on.

`angular.findWhere = function(collection,search) {
    var $filter = angular.element(document).injector().get("$filter"),
        refined = $filter('filter')(collection,search);
    return refined[0];
}`

then you just use it like this:

`angular.findWhere($scope.accounts,{permission: 'all'});`

Comment: I like this way, but I cannot reach it. It is written this kind of mistake: https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/unpr?p0=filterProvider%20%3C-%20filter                   Do you have any examples how it is working? Thanks

Comment: Here you go it's a working example. Please vote up my answer if you find it helpful. http://plnkr.co/edit/QyMbhEl6mKow8FhkgRAU?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Most simple way is use [lodash](http://lodash.com/) and write

```
$scope.filteredAccounts = _.where($scope.accounts,{permission: 'all'});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write custom filters in AngularJS. Here is a link to a document that talks about how to create one: https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_09

Your custom filter might look something like this:

```
myApp.filter('permissionFilter', function () {
    return function (accounts, permission) {
        var filtered = [];
        angular.forEach(accounts, function (account) {
          if (account.permission === permission) {
            filtered.push(account);
          }
        });
        return filtered;
    };
});
```

And the usage would be something like this:

```
  <div ng-controller="MainController">
    <div ng-repeat="account in accounts | permissionFilter:'all'">
      <p>{{ account.name }}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

This would allow you to use this filter to filter any kind of permission. In other words, you can change `'all'` to `'no'` and it will return Jem and Osama. You could take that a step further and bind to the filter variable, so you could let the user decide what they wanted to filter based on.

Here is a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/WVLPzO5YbBcl6lJ99fqI?p=preview%22Plunker%22) with a working example.